# Disable autocorrect in Safari text input

Tags: html, macos, safari

I'm using the autocorrect "off", etc. in input boxes on my site. However, Safari on Mac OS X still auto corrects text input.

This is what I have:

```html
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter a web address">
```

But when I test it on Safari version 9 ([Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)), it is still autocorrecting the text.

Is there a more robust answer? Is the new version of Safari overwriting it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add `spellcheck="false"` to your input.

```html
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter a web address" spellcheck="false">
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t2va9tgw/)

Comment: @hyperfkcb, this solution describes how to remove the spellcheck specifically for Safari. Sounds like you want to enable autocorrect. If so, then you just need to remove the spellcheck attribute and set all of the 'auto' attributes to true. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oucaqkqg/)

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS15's Safari (December 2021).

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do this with jQuery, you'll need to leave the quotes off of false.

```
$(this).prop("spellcheck", false); // this works

$(this).prop("spellcheck", "false"); // this does NOT properly set the property
```

Answer (score 1):

Change input type from text to search

```
<input type="search">
```

Or

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8325873

Comment: <input type="search"> ? Are your sure ? Doesn't seem to work here (latest version)